# API method for video frame in video.js

Tags: video.js

Is there a way to get the current frame number and a way to seek to a given frame?  It would be similar to the `currentTime` method

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [return frame number video js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593982/return-frame-number-video-js)